# Can I set client id manually in AWS Cognito?

Tags: authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito, access-token

We are in the middle of doing some updates to Cognito for an already in use system. If possible, I'd like to keep the current client IDs and keys the same so that we don't have to go update all the device clients.

Is there a way to manually set client ID and key in AWS Cognito? I was unable to find documentation supporting this.

Comment: What do you mean by Client IDs? Are you referring to App Client IDs, or anything with user specific device remember settings in Amazon Cognito?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Cognito does not provide us the ability to set our own app client IDs or secrets. They are both auto-generated.

If you are constantly running into cases where you need to re-create your app client, I would recommend creating an endpoint to retrieve app client information for your applications **given the app client name which can be set by you upon creating of the app client**.

You can achieve this through a combination of Cognito APIs.

1. Use [DescribeUserPoolDomain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUserPoolDomain.html) to obtain the UserPoolId given the Cognito domain.
2. Use [ListUserPoolClients](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUserPoolClients.html) to obtain all the App Clients given the UserPoolId. This will give you a list of pairs (ClientName, ClientId). He're you will be able to get the ClientId corresponding to the ClientName you set originally.
3. Use [DescribeUserPoolClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUserPoolClient.html) to obtain the App Client Secret given the ClientId and UserPoolId.